# "About Me" is missing on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013

After upgrading site collections from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 we can't find "About Me". Instead we see "My Settings" for Default and My Site Web Applications.

Together with My Settings we see "Newsfeed", "OneDrive", "Sites" on the top right corner.

Profile Service and Profile Sync Service are both running and works well.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Check my site permissions - ensure you ave not locking down your profiles.

The sites that you upgraded are they running in 2013 mode?  If not - try a trial upgrade (it creates a temporary site collection) so you can review and see if that resolves your issue.

Also check that you can view the profile pages directly - the about me page is what you'll hit when navigating to user page usually via search or just clicking on there name from a list context.  If you get an error here - you can track that from ULS - and will most likely be permission related.

Comment: Thanks, Jesus Shelby, just recreating UPS from scratch helped with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate the Farm-level Feature: `Social Tags and Note Board Ribbon Controls`

Once that feature is enabled, the "About Me" will replace "My Settings" in the drop-down under your Username.